# TFS Build Configuration: get all the Work Items Details for a particular build

Tags: tfs

I have triggered a build using the existing TFS build definition. But after successful build I am unable to get list of Work Items which are available in the source code against which build has been done.

Let say I am going to build my current branch and it contains code check-in for 100 Work Items. Now my requirement is that code changes for how many Work Items have been done i.e. I need details of all those 100 Work Items in the build definition log files?

**Please suggest what changes need to be done to get all the Work Item details in log file of successful TFS build.**

I am using TFS 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check in pending changes, you need to add the work items in Related Work Items section. For your scenario, you can save a query for the 100 work items, select all 100 work items and drag them to the Related Work Items section, and then check in with the changes. In this way, you'll get all related work items in Associated Work Items section in your build summary :

[image]

Update a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am adding related Work Items for each check In. but how can I see it in log file? I mean where I will find the list of work Item in successful build log.  Do I need to make any changes in build to avail it in log file ?

Comment: Thanks for you support. it help me to understand where can I find the details about all the work item. I have up voted and accepted the answer.

Comment: But I have one more query-- how can I see all the work Items details. Let say I have triggered TFS Build 2 times then in last build it will say that  "No change sets are submitted to build 'ABC…..'" where as I require list of all the work items. how can I get all the work items since the beginning?

Comment: I have asked my next query in a separate thread. Please have a look at below url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802920/tfs-build-xaml-template-at-associatechanges-step-get-all-the-work-items-since