# TFS Build XAML Template at “AssociateChanges” step get all the Work Items since begging of the source code branch created

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, tfs, build

I have asked a similar question

[TFS Build Configuration: get all the Work Items Details for a particular build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787309/tfs-build-configuration-get-all-the-work-items-details-for-a-particular-build)

And based on the answer of above question I have the below query. I decided to start a new thread for new question rather than confusing people in same thread.

I am using a default XAML template for workflow of TFS build configuration. **Now my requirement is that I need all the Work Items since beginning whenever I trigger a build event for any build definition regardless of last successful build.**

Let say I have triggered first TFS build and it is succeeded then I triggered 2nd build and that is also succeeded.

Then I have opened the log file of 2nd successful build and goes to Diagnostics Tab of last build. Inside Diagnostics tab there is a section as “Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build”

Inside this it will display a message like

> "No change sets are submitted to build 'ABC…..'"

**Whereas I require list of all the work items since beginning. 
Please suggest me the changes which need to be done in XAML template so that I can get all the work items since the beginning of source code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know, associate the changesets and work items only occurs since the last good build.

There is a simple workaround to achieve what you want, you can specify a previous changeset to queue a build, then build the latest changeset again, then you'll get the associated changesets and work items again. Refer to this blog: http://chamindac.blogspot.sg/2013/09/tfs-2012-get-release-build-with.html

Otherwise, you need to create a [MSBuild custom task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc(v=vs.120).aspx) that makes a call to TFS for the items. Check the links below:

- https://volatilecoding.com/2013/06/11/tfs-build-how-to-customize-work-item-association/
  (this solution is for TFS2010/TF2012 build process template, you'll
  need to work on TFS 2013 build process template).
- http://devgorilla.net/?p=104